# Email-to-activity processing - don't include attachments

Tags: email, activity, attachments

I LOVE me that email-to-activity processor.
But I'm using up all my disk space because it's also including the attachments from the emails I'm forwarding into CiviCRM.

I don't need the attachments in CiviCRM.

Is there an option or flag I can change to prevent the Email-to-Activity processor from including attachments?